# Asp.Net MVC4: Jquery Bundle is Blank

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple project that contains these two bundles:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Styles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Styles/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css"));
```

This seems to work fine locally (debug mode so they aren't bundled); however, once I published the files to my file system, and move them out to the server, it is no longer functioning correctly:

I can see that both (bundled) file references are on the page; however, if you look at what the server actually sent, both files are blank.

What would cause the server to send blank files for these two bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some more research, I could see for those two files the server was actually sending a 301 redirect response to a different generated file, and these generated files were the blank ones I was receiving.

Since this server has several applications and sites running on it (some mvc), I thought this might be some weird bug with the bundling system, and renamed my bundles from 'jquery' to just 'jq', since other applications are probably using those names, and that did solve the problem